# How to hide a common link on a particular page only?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

Let's say that n-pages of application contains a link to `page A`.
But that link actually placed in the template part of that n-pages.

Note that the `page A` also contains that template part. So that link is present in the `page A` too.

The idea is to hide the link to `page A` when the transition was happened from any other n-pages to `page A`. I.e. when we are on any of the n-pages then that link is present but is we are an the `page A` then that link is hidden.

How can I achieve that with a little effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rendered` attribute and check viewId in it. In yor case:

```
<h:commandLink rendered="#{view.viewId ne '/pageA.xhtml'}"/>
```

In this exmaple `h:commandLink` will be rendered in all pages except `pageA.xhtml`

Also you can pass parameters in your template by using [ui:param](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_parameters_tag.htm) tag. So you render link in template only if parameter true:

```
<!-- template.xhtml: -->
<h:commandLink rendered="#{renderLinkParam}"/>...<ui:insert name="myPage"/>
```

And use this code on your page to pass parameter:

```
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="renderLinkParam"  value="#{true}" />
        <ui:define name="myPage">...
        </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```